# Display ad again only if user has logged in and logged out

Tags: javascript, function, local-storage, event-listener, session-state

There is an ad within an application that displays and has a text link that says "I am not interested." If that link is clicked, the ad disappears. The only time the ad should display again is if the user logs out, and logs back in to that page.

I don't have much code to work with here, I was looking for general guidance on how to go about doing this. Not asking anyone to code it for me, but what would be the best route? Initially I have localStorage set on this function so it stores the data across sessions. Is there a way to clear the data when someone logs out, and logs back in?

(it's not much) but this is what I have going so far:

```
function dismissAd() {
  var dismissalButton = document.addEventListener("TEXT-LINK");
  dismissalButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var ad = document.querySelector("AD");
    ad.classList.add("hidden");
    localStorage.setItem("adAlreadyShown", true);
  });
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I think it depends solely on the infrastructure that you have. You can use local storage with the logout callback (if you have one). You can also make use of your backend database to store these type of counts. Also remember to clear localstorage once the ad is shown (if you happen to go with the localstorage option).